# Streaming audio over wifi: feasible and how?

Tags: linux, audio, stream, mp3, wifi

I'm evaluating building an application which, simplifying the requirements, records from a microphone equipped small computer (eg: a Raspberry PI) and streams the digitalized sound over wireless connection in almost realtime to a server on the same LAN (No Internet involved). Ideally, the server application would record different streams from various wifi microphones and mix them together..

I'm currently looking into obtain a pretty good quality out of this, comparable somehow to a 128Kb stereo MP3.

At this point, I'm still evaluating options here, so I'm also looking to see your opinion on the feasibility of this.. if you think it's doable, what libraries, APIs, protocols would you use? Consider that this will be likely deployed on Linux based embedded computers (for the wifi mic part) and Linux based servers.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should be able to stream audio via pulseaudio, or even via the ancient esound.

Answer (score 0):

I listen often Shoutcast on the iPad. This sounds pretty good to me. I do not know the kb/s rate there, I think they stream mp3. So I do not think this would be a big issue if you can live with the quality loss which comes with mp3. The bigger issue might be, how good your wireless connection is. When your network is pretty busy, there are more errors and lower speed. It also depends on the wireless standard and the hardware you are using. You may think about buffering, too.